# Ruby Stack failed to deploy on Google Developers Console

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform

I tried to deploy Ruby stack using Google Developers Console, but no success. I tried several times at  other project, error was always the same (below).

Do you have any idea why it keeps failing?

```
2014/10/23 15:59:44
rubyStackBox: PENDING
2014/10/23 15:59:55～2014/10/23 16:06:01
rubyStackBox: DEPLOYING
2014/10/23 16:06:11
rubyStackBox: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
Replica rubystackbox-eaeo failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated the issue you experienced several times and it also failed. What finally worked was playing with the zones/regions when deploying the ruby stack :

`Developers console > Click-to-deploy > Set MySQL password > Advanced Options`, choose a different zone and click `Deploy`.

Another useful tool when investigating this is Console Output. Even if the deployment fails, you can go to the `VM instance` and check `View Output` towards the bottom of the page. It will list all the packages and any errors encountered. The following command will achieve the same thing:

```
$ gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output <INSTANCE_NAME> --project <PROJECT_ID> --zone <ZONE_NAME>
```

Please advise if still seeing issues.

Comment: I have succeed to launch instance after changing zone and machine type!


---
Note: Ruby and Rails documentation (ri and RDoc) are installed in the background after software installation and configuration is complete. It usually takes about 10 minutes.
Zone: asia-east1-b
Image: ..
Machine Type: n1-standard-2
---

thanks for your advise

Comment: Success with Another settings like below:

Zone: us-central1-f
Machine Type: n1-standard-1

Comment: Sounds good. glad to hear that it worked. sometimes the zones/regions are at capacity thus the workaround for this issue.