# Deploying a Ruby Stack on Google Cloud Platform Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-compute-engine

Trying to install Ruby Stack via the Developers Console, https://console.developers.google.com/.

MyProject > Compute > Click to Deploy

Played with various combinations in the Advanced Settings, as suggested in the accepted answer on the question [Ruby Stack failed to deploy on Google Developers Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522970/ruby-stack-failed-to-deploy-on-google-developers-console)

Deployed various combinations of zone and instance size, always ending in the error:

`Replica rubystackbox-chnp failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times.`

Here are some output snippets found in the Serial Console.

```
WARNING - Timeout at i8042_flush:68!
All threads complete.
Found 0 serial ports
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@0,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@1,0
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=20971520
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@2,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@3,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@4,0
```

Then it repeats until,

```
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@252,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@253,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@254,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@255,0
Scan for option roms
Searching bootorder for: HALT
drive 0x000fd9d0: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520
Space available for UMB: 000c0000-000eb800
Returned 118784 bytes of ZoneHigh
e820 map has 7 items:
  0: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 = 1 RAM
  1: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 = 2 RESERVED
  2: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 = 2 RESERVED
  3: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bfffd000 = 1 RAM
  4: 00000000bfffd000 - 00000000c0000000 = 2 RESERVED
  5: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 = 2 RESERVED
  6: 0000000100000000 - 00000007c0000000 = 1 RAM
Unable to lock ram - bridge not found
Changing serial settings was 3/2 now 3/0
enter handle_19:
  NULL
Booting from Hard Disk...
```

After other long series, we get

```
Nov 13 05:49:06 rubystackbox-chnp init: Trying to re-exec init

INIT: version 2.88 reloading

gcm-Heartbeat:1415857752000
[   50.982407] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[   50.983602] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
Nov 13 05:49:22 rubystackbox-chnp kernel: [   50.982407] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
Nov 13 05:49:22 rubystackbox-chnp kernel: [   50.983602] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
Nov 13 05:49:23 rubystackbox-chnp kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
gcm-StatusUpdate:TIME=1415857775000;STATUS=COMMAND_FAILED;INVOCATION_ID=1
gcm-Heartbeat:1415857782000
gcm-Heartbeat:1415857812000
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Per @Marilu's suggestion, I tried again today and now it's working.

Comment: I tried to install yesterday and failed twice, today it just work fine. Are you on a trial period, I know they have some limitation on GCE.

Comment: What is your project name? What zone(s) were you trying to launch on?

Comment: @Marilu - yes, I'm on the trial period.

Comment: @MishaBrukman - The project_id is able-dryad-763. I tried launching in various zones with different machine sizes, as per the suggestion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522970/ruby-stack-failed-to-deploy-on-google-developers-console.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider launching [Ruby](https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby/cloud/google) or [JRuby](https://bitnami.com/stack/jruby/cloud/google) stacks via Bitnami.